# Finding joint distribution from pdf of sum

Tags: probability, random-variables, poisson-distribution

Let $X$ and $Y$ be *dependent* random variables, where $X$ follow a Poisson distribution with rate $\lambda_x$. Let their sum $Z = X + Y$ follows a Poisson distribution with rate $\lambda_z$.

Is this enough information to figure out the joint distribution of $(X, Y)$?

Comment: Where is this from?

Comment: Curiousity alone to be honest. Was chilling over a cup of coffee when this idea sparked and unfortunately I lacked the mathematical skills to answer my own question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: it is impossible in general to find joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ given $X$ follows a Poisson distribution with rate $λ_x$ and $Z=X+Y$ follows a Poisson distribution with rate $λ_z$. Other words, one can construct different examples of joint distributions of $X,Y$ such that all the above conditions are satisfied.

I assume here $\lambda_z>\lambda_x$.

**1st example.** Let $X\sim\Pi_{\lambda_x}$ and $Z\sim\Pi_{\lambda_z}$ be independent r.v.'s. Set $Y=Z-X$. Then $Z=X+(Z-X)=X+Y$.

In this case joint distribution of $(X,Y)=(X,Z-X)$ looks as follows:
$$
P(X=k, Z-X = m) = P(X=k, Z=m+k) = \dfrac{\lambda_x^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda_x}\times\dfrac{\lambda_z^{m+k}}{(m+k)!}e^{-\lambda_z},\ k\geq 0, \ m\geq -k.
$$

**2nd example.** For simplicity, I construct joint distribution for $\lambda_x=2$. Let $X\sim \Pi_2$ and construct $Y_0$ depending on $X$ s.t. $X+Y_0\sim\Pi_2$. After that we can choose another $Y_1\sim \Pi_{\lambda_z-\lambda_x}$ independent on $X$ and finally get $Y=Y_0+Y_1$.

Let the joint pmf of $(X,Y_0)$ looks as follows:
$$\begin{array}{r|c|c|c|c|c}
X & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & \ldots \\
Y_0\quad & & & & & \\ 
\hline
0 & \frac12e^{-2} & \frac32e^{-2} & \frac{2^2}{2}e^{-2} & \frac{2^3}{3!}e^{-2} & \ldots \\
1 & \frac12e^{-2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots \\
-1 & 0 & \frac12e^{-2} & 0 & 0 & \ldots \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Here 
$$
P(X=0,Y_0=0)= P(X=1,Y_0=-1)=P(X=0,Y_0=1) = \frac12e^{-2},
$$
$$
P(X=1,Y_0=0) = \frac32e^{-2}.
$$
Then 
$$
P(X+Y_0=0)=P(X=0,Y_0=0)+ P(X=1,Y_0=-1)=e^{-2}=P(X=0),$$
$$
P(X+Y_0=1)=P(X=0,Y_0=1)+ P(X=1,Y_0=0)=2e^{-2}=P(X=1).$$

Therefore, $X+Y_0$ is distributed as $X$. Next, choose another $Y_1\sim \Pi_{\lambda_z-2}$ independent on $X$ and $Y_0$ and finally get $Y=Y_0+Y_1$.

Then $Z=X+Y=X+Y_0+Y_1\sim\Pi_{\lambda_z}$ is distributed like a sum of two independent Poisson r.v. $X+Y_0\sim\Pi_{2}$ and $Y_1\sim \Pi_{\lambda_z-2}$.

Joint distribution of $(X,Y)=(X,Y_0+Y_1)$ looks as follows:
$$
P(X=k, Y=m) = P(X=k, Y_0=0)P(Y_1=m)+ P(X=k, Y_0=1)P(Y_1=m-1)+P(X=k, Y_0=-1) P(Y_1=m+1)$$
For example, when $k=0$, $m=1$
$$P(X=0, Y=1) = P(X=0, Y_0=0)P(Y_1=1)+ P(X=0, Y_0=1)P(Y_1=0)+P(X=0, Y_0=-1) P(Y_1=2)= \dfrac12(\lambda_z-2)e^{-\lambda_z}+\dfrac12e^{-\lambda_z}=\dfrac12(\lambda_z-1)e^{-\lambda_z}.
$$
This distribution differ from the distribution in 1st example.

Comment: Roughly the same idea can be used to construct $X$ Poisson $\lambda$ and $Y$ almost surely nonnegative but not Poisson such that $X+Y$ is Poisson $\mu$ for some prescribed $\mu>\lambda$.

Comment: @Did Yes, but I had troubles on this way with a lot of unknown variables in joint distribution and a lot of equations connecting them together. The simpler, the better.

Comment: No problem, I just wanted to mention that the idea used in your answer is quite powerful.