# Small question about Poisson variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, independence

I have small 2 questions:

1. Is the sum of two Poisson variables only then a Poisson variable, if they are independet?
2. If $X,Y$ are Poisson. And $X=Y$. Is $Z= X-Y$ also Poisson (if they are independet or not)?

Comment: Either you have a typo in 2 or $Z=0$. Also you should give some context like your thoughts on the problem. Nonetheless I'll give a small hint for 1: usually if you're thinking of whether you can remove an independence assumption entirely a good first test is for the variables $X$ and $X$, which are a good example of two non-independent variables with the same distribution.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen For 2) if $X,Y$ are two Poisson variables with parameter $\delta$ a $\gamma$. If $X=Y$ is it then true that the difference $Z=X-Y$ is not Poisson? (please look at both case: Independent and non-Independent)

Comment: Huh? If $X=Y$ then $Z = X-Y = 0.$ Not sure how to parse the part about the parameters but if they have different distributions, how can $X=Y$?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen And is this not the same as a Poisson variable which is distributed with parameter $0$?
Edit: no different distribution. I only want to know the cases when $X,Y$ are independet or not.

Comment: I suppose it is (usually $\lambda =0$ is not allowed, but I see no reason not to admit it as a degenerate case). Still this is a strange question, and not well-founded if the parameter for $X$ and $Y$ is different.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Please let me reformulate my question: If $X,Y$ are Poisson distributed, is $X-Y$ also Poisson distributed or not? (including the case that the difference could be Poisson with $\lambda = 0$)?

Comment: In that one uninteresting case where $X=Y$, yes. Otherwise... think about it. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, both with parameter $\lambda,$ what does the distribution of $X-Y$ look like? Don't calculate it.. just what does it look like?

Comment: To first question, see example here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2168580

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the 2nd question, assuming you didn't mean $X = Y$, you can find the distribution of $X - Y$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1061514/460426). It is called a [Skellam distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution) and looks quite complicated.